# Rise up circle using negative margin only and not using position?

Tags: html, css

How can I rise up the circle by using **negative margin** only? I don't want to use position.

```
.task6 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.task6_row {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.feature_item {
  width: 32%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.feature_number {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* position: absolute; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -12px;
  font-family: Arial, Tahoma;
}

.feature_name {}

.feature_desc {
  color: lightgray;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="task6">
  <div class="task6_row">
    <div class="feature_item">
      <div class="feature_number">1</div>
      <h2 class="feature_name">
        cheap price
      </h2>
      <p class="feature_desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, ratione?
      </p>
      <a class="example" href="">see example</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, [transform()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) will also move the element using negative values. Replace the margin-top property with the one below, declaring the amount you wish it to translate in the Y-axis and X-axis values. Example:

```
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the circle is dependable on its container, which has a margin of 5px. If you reset the margin-top of the container you will also move the circle.

ADD:

```
   .feature_item { margin:5px; margin-top:0px; }
   .feature_number { margin-top: -12px; }
```